# Generate token with RS256 and Jwts.builder().signWith() produces invalid signature

Tags: java, jwt, jjwt

Using the [JWT Java library](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) and producing a token with the **RS256** algorithm, I always get an invalid signature with the [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) debugger. Here is my example code, I tried to make it as simple as possible to start with my current project:

```
    // Create a legitimate RSA public and private key pair:
    KeyPair kp = RsaProvider.generateKeyPair();
    PublicKey publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

    String jwt = Jwts.builder().setSubject("Joe").signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, privateKey).compact();
```

This code is inspired from the test class [here](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/src/test/groovy/io/jsonwebtoken/JwtsTest.groovy).

Any idea what I could be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) debugger expects that you provide the public key associated with the private key used to sign the token encoded in the Public Key file (PKCS#8) format.

Ensure that you specify it using exactly that format, an example follows:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
BASE64 DATA
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: True indeed, providing the public key alongside it gives a valid signature.